# sort featured questions by "featured date" -- how?

Tags: support, sorting, bountied-tab, featured-tag

Is it possible to get a list of featured questions, sorted by date they became featured?

I'm trying to do this because I try to look at the list of featured questions every few days to see if there are any new ones I could answer.  But I'd love to be able to skip over old ones and only examine questions I haven't seen before.  Possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Featured, or bounty, questions are already sorted in the "Featured" tab by the date the bounty expires, soonest first.  Since bounties expire 7 days from being posted ("becoming featured"), this is effectively already the sort order, earlier-featured questions appearing first.

To find the new ones, browse to the last page and work backwards.

Comment: excellent, thanks for the info!